# How to use ref_cursor with user defined function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I written a code to return set of records as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (from_dt date, to_dt date, out sys_refcursor)
as
    cursor c
    is
    select max(cde)
    from table1
    where to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') between from_dt and to_dt
    group by id;

begin
        for i in c
        loop
            select function(i.cde) into v_cde from dual;
            
            open out for select column1, v_cde, column2, column2 from table2
            where to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') between from_dt and to_dt;
        end loop;
end;
```

After execute the above procedure all records are retruned correctly except `v_cde` function return value. It returns same value for all records.
I think `cde` value is not went under looping.
How can i use function along with ref_cursor in loop?.

I anyone have suggestions, tell me.

Comment: are you sure that procedure compiles ?

Comment: Yes...procedure complied.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f857f41e6b89294e9824ceec4ea5f46) please.

Comment: There's plenty wrong with this stored proc.  For one thing, why open a ref cursor multiple times in a loop?  All you'll get is the results for the last iteration of the loop, assuming there is a last iteration.  How are tables `table1` and `table2` related?  Why does your cursor `c` not select the `id` column from `table1`?  It gives you a bunch of max values of `cde`, grouped by `id`, without telling you which `id` each max value corresponds to.  Also, your parameter named `out` is an `IN` parameter: if you want to return it from your proc, you have to declare it `out out sys_refcursor`.

Comment: But the single biggest question is why bother with looping over a cursor at all?  I strongly suspect that the entire body of this stored proc could be replaced with a single query which you open the output ref cursor for.

Answer (score 2):

The given code is not complete as Barbaros is attempting to show. Here is a different attempt at completing the code. Even then, the procedure test still does not compile but the error is now reduced to the ref cursor problem:

LINE/COL ERROR

---

16/13    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
16/18    PLS-00361: IN cursor 'OUT' cannot be OPEN'ed

Changes to the example:

1. both table1 and table2 have been defined with what I think are the columns
2. function is defined at schema level
3. local variable v_cde is now defined
4. function is now defined at schema level

Here is the new example:

```
drop table table1;
drop table table2;

create table table1 (cde number, dt date, id number, from_dt date, to_dt date);

create table table2 (column1 number, v_cde number, column2 number, dt date, id number, from_dt date, to_dt date);

Rem This function returns the same numeric value given
create or replace function func1(arg1 number) return number is
  begin
    return arg1;
  end;
/
show errors;

CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE test (from_dt date, to_dt date, rf1 sys_refcursor)
as
    v_cde number;
    cursor c
    is
    select max(cde) cde
    from table1
    where to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') between from_dt and to_dt
    group by id;

begin
        for i in c loop
            v_cde := func1(i.cde);
            
            open rf1 for select column1, v_cde, column2, column2 from table2
            where to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') between from_dt and to_dt;
        end loop;
end;
/
show errors;
```